# Kicking members with on_member_join (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a bot that kicks members if they have something in their name. I am using discord.py:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  guildID = str(member.guild.id)
  if not guildID in banned:
    banned[guildID] = []
  for i in banned[guildID]:
    if member.name in i:
      #kick
      await kick(user, reason = "Username banned") #ERROR
      print("kicked" + str(member.id))
  await saveData()
```

How should I do the kicking?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `await member.kick(reason="Username banned")`, the command is defined in [the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=kick#discord.Member.kick).